# Как производить математические вычисления над определенной колонкой DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Как можно вычислить пример со следующим видом `“с_с = (с – с_min)/с_max”` со всеми элементами колонки `с`, и вывести в другой `dataframe`, где будут хранится данные из колонки `с` из прежнего `df` и вычисленные значения `c_c`?

Csv:

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,8,7,6
5,4,3,2
1,8,4,6
```

Скрипт:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nm

pd = pd.read_csv("test1.csv", delimiter=',')
pd.head(len(pd.index))
c_min = pd['c'].min()
c_max = pd['c'].max()
print(c_min, c_max)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd = pd.read_csv("test1.csv", delimiter=',')
```

Не делайте так - не называйте разные сущности одним именем. У вас тут переменная `pd` перекрыла алиас `pd` пакета `pandas` и вы дальше по коду не сможете этим алиасом пользоваться. Называйте датафрейм стандартно - `df`.

А так то всё просто. Скопировать колонку в новый датафрейм можно с помощью `copy`:

```
df1 = df[['c']].copy()
```

Обратите внимание, что скобок две пары. С одной парой если сделать, то это будет `Series`, а не `Dataframe`.

Дальше просто записываете формулу как есть, но с использованием датафрейма:

```
df1['c_c'] = (df1['c'] - df1['c'].min())/df1['c'].max()
```

Ну или можете использовать ваши заранее посчитанные переменные для `min` и `max`, разницы нет.